# python-notify module & cron: gio.Error

Tags: python, cron, env

I'm asking some help to show notifications using [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab), because everything I've tried do not work. The display is not initilised when the script is launched by cron. When I start it manually, that's work.
The codes I've tried:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # coding: utf8

    import subprocess
    import os

    #os.environ.setdefault("XAUTHORITY", "/home/guillaume" + "/.Xauthority")

    #os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')     # do not work
    #os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'               # do not work
    print = os.environ

    cmd2 = 'notify-send test'
    subprocess.call(cmd2, shell=True)

    # more code, which is working (using VLC)
    cmd3 = "cvlc rtp://232.0.2.183:8200 --sout file/mkv:/path/save/file.mkv" # to download TV's flow
    with open("/path/debug_cvlc.log", 'w') as out:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd3, stderr=out, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    pid = proc.pid                  # to get the pid
    with open("/path/pid.log", "w") as f:
       f.write(str(pid))            # to write the pid in a file
    # I'm using the pid to stop the download with another cron's task, and to display another notify message. 
    # Download and stop is working very well, and zenity too. But not notify-send
```

Thanks

#### Edit: here are the environment variables I have for this cron's script:

```
{'LANG': 'fr_FR.UTF-8', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'PWD': '/home/guillaume', 'LOGNAME': 'guillaume', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin', 'HOME': '/home/guillaume', 'DISPLAY': ':0.0'}
```

#### Edit2: I'm calling my script in cron like this:

```
45 9 30 6 * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /home/path/script.py > /home/path/debug_cron_on.log 2>&1
```

I precise I have two screens, so I think DISPLAY:0.0 is the way to display this notify..
But I don't see it.

#### Edit3: It appears that I've a problem with notify-send, because it's working using zenity:

```
subprocess.call("zenity --warning --timeout 5 --text='this test is working'", shell=True)
```

I have notify-send version 0.7.3, and I precise that notify-send is working with the terminal.

#### Edit4: Next try with python-notify.

```
import pynotify
pynotify.init("Basic")
n = pynotify.Notification("Title", "TEST")
n.show()
```

The log file show this: (in french)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/path/script.py", line 22, in <module>
        n.show()
    gio.Error: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée 
 #Translating: Unable to connect : Connection refused
```

So, I have problem with dbus? what is this?

### Solution: Get the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS before creating the cron order:

```
cron = CronTab()
dbus = os.getenv("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS")   # get the dbus
# creating cron  
cmd_start = "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=" + str(dbus) + " && export DISPLAY=:0.0 && cd /path && python /path/script.py > path/debug_cron.log 2>&1"
job = cron.new(cmd_start)
job = job_start.day.on(self.day_on) # and all the lines to set cron, with hours etc..
cron.write()             # write the cron's file
```

Finally, the cron's line is like that:

```
20 15 1 7 * export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-M0JCXXbuhC && export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python script.py
```

Then the notification is displaying. Problem resolved !! :)

Comment: Try re-installing `libnotify4` Check [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify4/+bug/748159).

Comment: I tried to re-install dbus, libnotify4 but nothing happens... Thank you, it seems to be a bug from my Ubuntu's install.

Comment: I've found a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623289/pynotify-runs-fine-interactively-but-crashes-when-run-programmatically-on-fedo) but the solution doesn't works for me. Damned!

Comment: Is the dbus daemon up for you? Check `sudo service dbus status` and also check the value of `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from within the script, and see if it is different from your shell's environment value. In general, cron runs with a reduced environment set, so it is quite possible for some environment variable to be missing from your cron environment. Since I'm using ubuntu, and you are on kubuntu, I think this should be the cause.

Comment: Anyway, I found a solution ! The notify is working when I add: `os.environ.setdefault("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS", "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-M0JCXXbuhC")`. But I think I will be working just for my computer, this is not a real solution for the others. Maybe using `try notify/except DBUS="unix:etc"`
Edit: Sorry I have not seen your response

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have read the result of `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'` in a terminal. But when I try to read it in the script, there's an error. (don't remember the error)

Comment: Now that you have one working version, you can check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28496/46799) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3302240/1860929) to access the dbus session variables generically on any unix system

Comment: Ok, I've the solution and edited my question/response. Thank you very much to help me to solve this problem !!

Comment: Cool then. Don't forget to accept, upvote, and hand out the bounty :D

Comment: No problem! In 16 hours I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the cron like

```
45 9 30 6 * DISPLAY=:0.0 python /home/path/script.py > /home/path/debug_cron_on.log 2>&1
```

which is incorrect, since you are not exporting the `DISPLAY` variable, and the subsequent command does not run.

Try this instead

```
45 9 30 6 * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && cd /home/path/ && python script.py >> debug_cron.log 2>&1
```

Also, you are setting the `DISPLAY` variable within your cron job as well, so try if the cron job works without exporting it in the job line

```
45 9 30 6 * cd /home/path/ && python script.py >> debug_cron.log 2>&1
```

**EDIT**

While debugging, run the cron job every minute. Following worked for me:

Cron entry

```
* * * * *  cd /home/user/Desktop/test/send-notify && python script.py
```

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
print os.environ

cmd2 = 'notify-send test'
subprocess.call(cmd2, shell=True)
```

**EDIT 2**

Using `pynotify`, script.py becomes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pynotify
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

pynotify.init("Basic")
n = pynotify.Notification("Title", "TEST123")
n.show()
```

and cron entry becomes

```
* * * * *  cd /home/user/Desktop/test/send-notify && python script.py
```

**EDIT 3**

One environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is missing from the cron environment.
It can be set in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id/28496#28496) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302240/running-a-python-script-from-crontab) fashion

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited my question with the modification. But the notification don't appear any more. I've also tried to add `&& cd /home/path/` but no change.

Comment: @Guillaume which user's crontab do you use? Are you trying this locally, or on a remote server? This will only display the message if you do it locally for your logged in user's crontab.

Comment: I'm trying to display locally, not on a server. But I've tried to display a message with zenity, and it's working. There's a problem with notify-send

Comment: @Guillaume I tried things locally, and it works for me. the script and cron entry are already there. I've `notify-send 0.7.6`

Comment: Same version 0.7.6 on Kubuntu 14.04 for me -_-'  ... Very weird

Comment: @Guillaume You will have to give the remainder of the script as well, I guess. Because, the part you have given already works for me after some changes.

Comment: I've updated my question with all the code, but the end is working. I think I will use zenity, it's not very important...

Comment: @Guillaume Well if my answer/discussion helped, don't forget to accept and upvote this answer :)

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for few days and I will vote for you if nobody finds a real solution, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think I have found the bug, (next edit in my question). Have you an idea?

Comment: @Guillaume this one also works for me. Check edits to my answer. I think you missed out the `DISPLAY` variable, check if adding that helps

Comment: Same issue, and the DISPLAY var was called in the cron line. With `os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')` I've the same gio.Error

Answer (score 0):

crontab is considered an external host -- it doesn't have permission to write to your display.

Workaround: allow anyone to write to your display. Type this in your shell when you're logged in:

```
xhost +
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand, no need the "os.environ" ?

Comment: either do `os.environ['DISPLAY']=':0'` in Python, or in the call: `subprocess.call('DISPLAY=:0 '+cmd2, shell=True)`.  The latter relies on you running the Bash shell, but that's pretty common.

Comment: It don't work, here is the return of the log file: `access control disabled, clients can connect from any host`. But the notification don't display on the screen

Comment: hmm.  Try the long form of `DISPLAY`, with the hostname/IP address and `:0`.  See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable

Comment: same issue with `:0`, I have 2 screnns so I think `:0.0` is better.
But with one screen, (I tried) nothing append...